# FieldInfo.GetValue returns null

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this piece of code:

```
FieldInfo fi = this.GetType().GetField(StringConstants.UNDERSCORE + phase, 
                                       BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    if (fi != null)
    {
        itemPhase = fi.GetValue(this) as IItemPhase;
    }

    if (itemPhase != null) 
    {
        _currentPhase = phase;
        _itemVo.Phase = phase;
        itemPhase.PreparePhase();
    }
```

`FieldInfo fi` gets correct value, so the field was found.

[image]

But `FieldInfo.GetValue` returns always null:

[image]

... and the Type matches:

[image]

Anyone knows why?

Comment: please provide minimal complete compilable example

Comment: have you tried it with another instance except the one you are calling from?

Comment: Perhaps `as IItemPhase` is leading to *NULL*

Comment: @prizm1 no I haven't but I don't see a point in it.

Comment: @user3185569 no. Without as it still return null.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski What if the value is actually *NULL*. Have you tried `this._buildPhase` ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I think I presented minimal and and complete example to have full view on the problem

Comment: @user3185569, wow, I think you might be right!

Comment: @JerrySwitalski split the line `itemPhase = fi.GetValue(this) as IItemPhase;` into two - the first that calls `GetValue`, the second to do the cast and then check the type of the object that `GetValue` actually returns.

Comment: Did you create a watch for `fi.GetValue(this)`? I bet it returns either `null` or not an instance of `IItemPhase`.

Comment: I think @JerrySwitalski has spotted the issue...

Comment: @BryanWoodford No, because we already said that to the user in the comments above and he said that even without the `as`, it is still *NULL*

Comment: @user3185569 - that's what I was referring to :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems the reference `this._buildPhase` is actually pointing to *NULL* and that's why you're getting this behavior.